# Find a conformal map of the given domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a complex function that maps the region $$D =\left\{|z|<1, \left|z- \frac{1}{2}\right|>\frac {1}{2}\right\}$$ conformally on to the upper half plane.

Can somebody help me to find the conformal map of the above domain with step by step explanation of the map? I think this is something about Lunar domain and I need to be able to map the first intersection of the domain in to the vertical strip passing through $\frac {1}{2}$ and $1$, and then map the vertical strip to the unit disk by exponential. Am I thinking this right? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* Moving away the exceptional point $z=1$ to infinity seems a good idea. What does the region look like after applying $z\mapsto \frac1{z-1}$?

Answer (score 3):

$$z\mapsto\exp\left(\pi i\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$$ This is the composition of the following functions:

1. $z\mapsto 1-z$
2. $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$
3. $z\mapsto z-\frac{1}{2}$
4. $z\mapsto 2\pi i \,z$
5. $z\mapsto \exp(z)$

Answer (score 2):

$$L_1(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$$ will send the domain into the region between the vertical lines $x=-1$ and $x=-\frac{1}{2}$.   Then you translate with
$$L_2(z)=z+1$$
Now you have the region between $x=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}$.  Next, you rotate $90$ degrees with 
$$ L_3(z)=iz$$

Finally, you take
$$L_4(z)=e^{4\pi z}$$
which sends the strip onto the uppper half plane.