# Conformal equivalence between annulus and the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I'm trying to do the following problem:

"Let $A$ be the region inside the disk $D(1,1)$ and outside the disk $\overline{D(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}})$. Construct the conformal equivalence between $A$ and the upper half plane $\Pi^{+}$ "

I know how to construct conformal equivalences between the unit disc and the upper half plane:

$$ w = i\frac{1+z}{1-z}, z = \frac{w-i}{w+i}$$

But, what do I do for the annulus? How can I extend it there?

Comment: It's been a long tine since I've done this stuff, but I don't see how this can be.  A conformal equivalence would be a homeomorphism, but the upper half plane is simply connected and an annulus is not.  Am I confused about something?

Comment: @saulspatz You could be correct about that, but since the problem is asking me to do it I figured that it might be possible. Am I mistaken in thinking that the region $A$ is an annulus?

Comment: $A$ is not an annulus but a "half moon" as the circles are inner tangent at the origin; as a hint (not really in the mood to work out the details so that remains for OP), send the outer circle to the imaginary axis (standard Mobius unit disc to right half plane translating the outer circle first to the unit circle) with the origin at $i\infty$ which means the inner circle is sent to a parallel line and if the orientation is right the region $A$ is sent to the strip inside the two vertical lines; from there, an appropriately scaled exponential works

Comment: this question gives a model for this type of problem, so one needs to adjust the constants only https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268742/find-a-conformal-map-of-the-given-domain

Comment: @Conrad That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: @saul no problem  - this type of region is "simplest" that is not bounded by a Jordan curve but is bounded and simply connected so is popular in exercises as above

Comment: Yes, I didn't even draw a picture, just took it for granted it was an annulus.  I'm sure I did this one when I was young, but that was a long, long time ago.

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for the link. In there, the first transformation used was $\frac{1}{z-1}$, for my problem would it work if I used $\frac{1}{z-2}$ and then follow it up $z+2$, $iz$, and $e^{4\pi z}$?